# User Permission Mask from NetworkCredentials

Tags: c#, sharepoint, wss-3.0, networkcredentials

Although I am currently developing this WinForms application on our Sharepoint server I intend for the finished program to function from any computer on the Domain. I'm using the WSS web services to get all the information I use from Sharepoint.

I have written some code which will check Sharepoint Permission masks, with logical OR against mask, for all the permissions it covers but I am having trouble returning the Sharepoint mask for the current user. I would like users to be able to log right in through Windows Authentication so this was my immediate idea.

```
NetworkCredential credentails = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
var userInfo = userGroupService.GetUserInfo(credentails.UserName);
```

However although I am able to return the permission collection for the entire Sharepoint site with `DefaultNetworkCredentials` (as in bellow snippet) the properties are empty strings, so I can't use it to get the UserName.

```
permissionService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
permissionService.Url = "http://localhost/mySite/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx";
// Web service request works
XmlNode node = permissionService.GetPermissionCollection(siteName, "Web");
// But I need to identify current user from this collection somehow still
```

I read that Windows Authentication suffers from a [double-hop issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx), which I want to avoid, but as I am developing on the server Sharepoint & IIS are running, I can't see this causing an immediate issue.

Is there a way around this or a better way to get the current users permission mask?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would do what you are looking for, but have you considered using an account that is "trusted for delegation". The double-hop should be permitted when the service account is trusted for delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current user for wss will always be the same as the user currently logged on to the pc

```
var userInfo = userGroupService.GetUserInfo(Environment.UserDomainName +@"\"+ Environment.UserName);
```

or to get the permissions for the currently logged on user

```
XmlNode currentUserPermission = userGroupService.GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with an issue where the authentication cannot move beyond one remote host; this is known as the "one-hop" limitation.

To overcome this, you have to get into "Constrained Delegation," where a computer/account are expressly authorized to receive and accept authentication credentials from another computer/account. This is set up in Active Directory by defining the appropriate Service Principal Names (SPN's) on either "end" of the delegation.

You can get more details about Constrained Delegation [here.](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=What%20is%20constrained%20delegation?)

Good luck! CD can be a bit of a pain to set up, so tread carefully.

Comment: Can you cite any sources for the "one-hop" limitation or explain further? While it's useful to know about, I can't see how this applies to me as I am not developing on a remote host.

Comment: I don't have a link in hand, but the general concept is that from point A to point B, a Windows Authentication credential is negotiated directly, such that A presents an identity that B has authenticated such that it now trusts what A presented. If that credential is then passed to C, C may "see" that credential, recognize it is authenticated, but had no part in the authentication and doesn't trust "B" to present one. That's the "one-hop." Constrained delegation instructs "C" that it may accept a credential from "B".